# Secured Web Service Exception: This service requires <wsse:Security>, which is missing

Tags: java, web-services, security, encryption, jboss

I have a problem with web service messaging.

1) Jboss 4.2.3GA

2) Web Service class that is Stateless EJB. It uses encryption and annotated like this:

```
@Local
@Stateless
@EndpointConfig(configName = "Standard WSSecurity Endpoint")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@WebService
```

3) Web Service resides in **Module_1**

4) Client is MBean. It has following annotations:

```
@Service(name = "MyWebServiceClient")
@Local(MyWebServiceClient.class)
@Management(MyWebServiceClient.class)
```

5) **MyWebServiceClient** resides in **Module_2**

6) **Module_1** has META-INF directory with following WS related content:

- jboss-wsse-server.xml
- server.keystore
- server.truststore

**jboss-wsse-server.xml** has following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-ws-security xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/ws-security/config" 
                   xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/ws-security/config 
                   www.jboss.com/ws-security/schema/jboss-ws-security_1_0.xsd">

<key-store-file>META-INF/server.keystore</key-store-file>
<key-store-password>qwerty</key-store-password>
<key-store-type>jks</key-store-type>

<trust-store-file>META-INF/server.truststore</trust-store-file>
<trust-store-password>qwerty</trust-store-password>
<trust-store-type>jks</trust-store-type>

<key-passwords>
    <key-password alias="server" password="qwerty"/>
    <key-password alias="client" password="qwerty"/>
</key-passwords>

<config>
    <sign type="x509v3" alias="server"/>
    <encrypt type="x509v3" alias="client"/>
    <requires>
        <signature/>
        <encryption/>
    </requires>
</config>
</jboss-ws-security>
```

7) **Module_2** has its' META-INF folder with following files:

- jboss-wsse-client.xml
- standard-jaxws-client-config.xml
- client.keystore
- client.truststore

**jboss-wsse-client.xml** contains following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-ws-security xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/ws-security/config"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/ws-security/config  
               http://www.jboss.com/ws-security/schema/jboss-ws-security_1_0.xsd">

<key-store-file>META-INF/client.keystore</key-store-file>
<key-store-password>qwerty</key-store-password>
<key-store-type>jks</key-store-type>

<trust-store-file>META-INF/client.truststore</trust-store-file>
<trust-store-password>qwerty</trust-store-password>
<trust-store-type>jks</trust-store-type>

<key-passwords>
    <key-password alias="server" password="qwerty"/>
    <key-password alias="client" password="qwerty"/>
</key-passwords>

<config>
    <sign type="x509v3" alias="client"/>
    <encrypt type="x509v3" alias="server"/>
    <requires>
        <signature/>
        <encryption/>
    </requires>
</config>
</jboss-ws-security>
```

**standard-jaxws-client-config.xml** contains following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws-config xmlns="urn:jboss:jaxws-config:2.0" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jaxws-config:2.0 jaxws-config_2_0.xsd">

<client-config>
    <config-name>Standard WSSecurity Client</config-name>
    <post-handler-chains>
        <javaee:handler-chain>
            <javaee:protocol-bindings>##SOAP11_HTTP</javaee:protocol-bindings>

            <javaee:handler>
                <javaee:handler-name>WSSecurityHandlerOutbound</javaee:handler-name>
                <javaee:handler-class>org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.jaxws.WSSecurityHandlerClient
                </javaee:handler-class>
            </javaee:handler>
        </javaee:handler-chain>
    </post-handler-chains>
</client-config>

</jaxws-config>
```

Both modules merged after build process to the same jar. So META-INF contains all this xml and encription files.

The problem is that when I try to send a message from Client MBean, web service generates exception:

> org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPFaultException: This service requires < wsse:Security >, which is missing.

As I know it means that incoming soap-message doesn't contain sing header from client.
After activating tracing soap messaging in log4j I see following message body from client:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<S:Body>
    <ns2:addPoint xmlns:ns2='http://x.y.z.com/'>
        <deviceId>Device 1</deviceId>
        <color>GREEN</color>
    </ns2:addPoint>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

But sign properties are specified in server and client xmls (see tat ).
So I can't understand why result message is not signed off.

May be problem is that all configuration files reside in the same META-INF?
Does it matter?

Need help.

Comment: Message body is not encrypted - encryption doesn't work. Very strange.

I've found one mistake in jboss-wsse-*.xml files. Wrong order of xml tags. Tag < key-store-password > must follow after <key-store-type>

This is xsd structure requirement. I've changed the order but encryption still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the reason why encryption did not work.
The structure of the project was as following:

```
EAR:
...META-INF
...client.jar
......META-INF
.........standard-jaxws-client-config.xml
.........jboss-wsse-client.xml
.........client.keystore
.........client.truststore
......org
........myproject
.................
...server.jar
......META-INF
.........jboss-wsse-server.xml
.........server.keystore
.........server.truststore
......org
........myproject
.................
```

The problem was that client can't find standard-jaxws-client-config.xml. Message was not encrypted.

When I copied this file to EAR/META-INF the encryption was done successfully, message was successfully transmitted to and decrypted on the server side.

I think it's because JBoss searches standard-jaxws-client-config.xml in the class path of ear file.

New file structure I use:

```
EAR:
...META-INF
......standard-jaxws-client-config.xml            <------- file placed here
...client.jar
......META-INF
.........jboss-wsse-client.xml
.........client.keystore
.........client.truststore
......org
........myproject
.................
...server.jar
......META-INF
.........jboss-wsse-server.xml
.........server.keystore
.........server.truststore
......org
........myproject
.................
```

If server and client are deployed as single files (without ear packaging) then placing this file under client/META-INF works fine.

As I realised this problem depends on path resolution.